# Run clean task before every build automatically in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-task

I want to run a project "clean" before the `assembleRelease` task in Gradle.

How can I trigger the clean task basically before **everything**?

Answer (score 3):

In gradle you can use the `dependsOn` method.

```
B.dependsOn A
```

In this way:

- task B depends on task A
- gradle executes A task everytime before the B task execution.

In your case:

```
assembleRelease.dependsOn clean
```

Comment: the buildscript

Comment: @Xerus Which one and where? `Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: It needs to be within the `tasks { }` block. Which buildscript depends on which project you want to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this, what I needed to do was have this in the

```
    android {
    afterEvaluate { 
       assemble(*your task here*)debug clean
}
```

and now it works great

Comment: That syntax does not look sound. What is this line supposed t do?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to execute the clean task first per each build variant

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def capitalizedVariant = variant.name.capitalize()
            def assembleVariantTask = project.tasks."assemble${capitalizedVariant}"
            assembleVariantTask.dependsOn clean
        }
    }
}
```